ROC of Laplace Transform of a time shifted impulse signal

If x(t) is of finite duration and is absolutely integrable, then the ROC is the entire s-plane.

This is stated and proved formally in the book of signals and systems by Oppenheim in the context of Laplace Transform.
If $$x(t)=\delta(t+1),$$then
$$X(s) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(t+1) e^{-st}dt= e^{s}, \quad \forall s \text{ except } \infty$$
So, the ROC does not include infinity.
Why doesn't the ROC include the entire s-plane?
Conditions that x(t) is of finite duration and is absolutely integrable are also fulfilled.

Infinity is not a number and it doesn't make sense to say \$s=\infty\$.
$$ \Bigg| \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(t+1)e^{-st} \: \text{d}t \Bigg|= \big|e^s\big| < \infty \: \forall \: s\in \mathbb{C}  \tag1$$
No matter what you choose \$s\$ to be the integral will never diverge. Hence, the ROC is the entire s-plane.
